# Convert file contents to a single line in ansible or jinja2 with \n characters replacing original newlines

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to take the contents of a file and print them as a single line string.

For example if I have a file with the following contents:

```
Line one
Line two

Line three
```

I would like an ansible / jinja2 template that will produce a variable with value:

`Line one\nLine two\n\nLine three`

When I use the contents of `lookup('file', 'example.txt')` the newlines are printed out instead of replaced by the text `\n`

The jinja2 filters I can think of usually do the *reverse* of this, `to_nice_yaml` or `to_nice_json` for example.

Comment: Did `{{ lookup('file', 'example.txt') | replace(newline, '\n') }}` not work for you (where `newline` is `vars: newline: "\n"` to get out of yaml-quoting hell)?

Comment: That doesn't work, but it led me down the rabbit-hole of what does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve this:

`{{ lookup('file', 'example.txt') | replace('\n', '\\n') }}`